# Invalid credentials: Google API calendar

Tags: google-app-engine, oauth, google-api, google-calendar-api, google-api-java-client

I am new to using Google APIs. I followed steps to setup Google Calendar sample code in eclipse using Google client library. I deployed the code to app engine using the cmd command- mvn appengine:update (when tried to deploy through eclipse it gave me an error saying the project is not an App Engine project). Deploying through command line worked and I could launch my web application.

Suddenly, after few API request calls, started getting invalid credentials error:

> error:401
>   domain:global
>   location: authorization
>   locationtype : header
>   message: invalid credentials
>   reason: auth error

I searched this error and found it may occur if your auth token is invalid or expired. I am not sure what I need to do to get a new auth token. In my case, there is a client_secrets.json file which has the client secrets. I did not put/save or use the auth token anywhere in the code. Following is what I remember when I deployed the code for the first time:

- There was some token which I was asked to paste on the cmd as I was deploying using the command line. After that I could launch my application.
- After that whenever I deployed my code and launched the application, there was no authorization(which happened the first time) and I could use the application and the API subsequently.
- Suddenly I started getting invalid credentials error.

I was using client_secrets.json generated from the developer's console and I did not provide auth token anywhere in the code and I did not save it either. I read that a refresh token can be used and that can avoid expiration of the auth token.

Currently, the issue is that I am getting invalid credentials error and I believe it is because of expiration of auth token. I am not aware about the solution in this case. It is the sample code provided by Google and I believe it automatically handles Oauth authorization (unlike the case where we programmatically call an Oauth url, get a token, store it somewhere and provide it with our subsequent requests). What do I need to do with the sample code so as to resolve this and not to run into the error in future?

Also that the application is running fine locally, but the authorization issue comes when it is deployed on the cloud. Thanks.

Comment: Can you link to the code sample from Google?

Comment: The sample code is available at: https://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client.samples/ google-api-java-client-samples..I basically followed 1)youtube video at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tVIIgcIqoPw and 2) instructions at: http://samples.google-api-java-client.googlecode.com/hg/calendar-appengine-sample/instructions.html to checkout and setup the sample code.

Comment: Please let me know if you need more information. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

The copy/paste token was actually unrelated to the actual credentials being used by the app for accessing the Calendar API; on the command line, it was the App Engine SDK getting permission to modify your App Engine project by uploading the sample app, regardless of what the app itself does.

Now, for the real issue here, it actually seems to be a bug where the `GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow` somehow receives an authorization code response which doesn't contain a `refreshToken`, only an `accessToken`, and then still goes on to store it in Datastore. Normally, the flow you see is expected to pop up a page saying "This app would like to: ... Have offline access" for the user on the first load, and then your app is supposed to get an `accessToken` and `refreshToken` pair, where the `accessToken` typically expires within 1 hour but then the `Credential` object knows how to automatically catch the `401` exception and execute the `refreshToken` to get a new `accessToken`, all under the hood. This could either be considered a bug in the backend server for returning a credential which lacks a refreshToken, or a bug in the client logic for still assuming there's a refreshToken and thus getting stuck rather than re-issuing a request for access capabilities.

Fortunately, there's an easy workaround. Right now, the fact that you're seeing the `401` error means there's a sticky malformed credential stored in your Datastore and possibly also your Memcache. Navigate to your `appengine.google.com` page, and assuming you aren't already serving a live production-critical web application there, go to `Datastore Viewer` on the left, look for the `Query -> By kind:` drop-down menu, to find `StoredCredential`, check all the items assuming they likely all came from your Calendar sample, and click "Delete". Also navigate to `Memcache Viewer` on the left-hand-side menu, and then click `Flush Cache`.

Now, it appears the reason the backends are trying to return credentials lacking a refreshToken is due to the client trying to incorrectly make use of "auto-approval". This is evidenced by the fact that when I create a brand-new client id with a new JSON client_secrets, then on just the *very first* time loading the sample calendar app, I find with my logging statements inside the `src/main/java/com/google/api/services/samples/calendar/appengine/server/Utils.java` file:

```
Credential credential = newFlow().loadCredential(userId);
if (credential.getRefreshToken() != null) {
  logger.log(Level.SEVERE, "Refresh token is not null");
} else {
  logger.log(Level.SEVERE, "Refresh token is null!");
}
```

then I do get a refreshToken for each unique login username I try to access it with. However, if I purge the credential from Datastore and Memcache, forcing a re-authentication on a subsequent request, I stop seeing the approval prompt and my credentials stop having refreshTokens, thus causing them to stop working 1 hour later.

**Solution (tl;dr)**

After purging your Datastore for all entities of kind `StoredCredential` and flushing your Memcache, simply add `.setApprovalPrompt("force")` to the newFlow() method inside of `src/main/java/com/google/api/services/samples/calendar/appengine/server/Utils.java`; the method will look like this:

```
static GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow newFlow() throws IOException {
  return new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Builder(HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY,
      getClientCredential(), Collections.singleton(CalendarScopes.CALENDAR)).setDataStoreFactory(
      DATA_STORE_FACTORY).setAccessType("offline").setApprovalPrompt("force").build();
}
```

Optionally, add some logging where the credential is obtained (it's generally bad practice to log the actual accessToken and especially the refreshToken, but during debugging doing it once or twice probably doesn't hurt :), and re-update your app. You'll find that the first time you access your app, you'll get the approval prompt now, and then it should safely work forever since the refreshToken never expires and is now saved in your Datastore.

Note that there's a limit on the number of refreshTokens per client/userId pair ever issued, and if you do purge your Datastore/Memcache during debugging, it effectively leaks a refreshToken. The behavior is just that after 25 such tokens, the earlier ones will automatically be deactivated. See the [oauth2 docs](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2#expiration) for more info on that limit.

Comment: Since things were not moving forward, I in the meantime created a new project on Google Developer's console and linked my application to the new project just to test how long the application works before giving auth error this time. I will post my observations for that. I will also certainly try your workaround by returning to my previous Google console's project and let you know the results and observations soon. Thanks a lot for your response.

Comment: Note that if you didn't test the application in the new project using the "local" mode first, then most likely the new project's app will continue working indefinitely unless you delete the items from its Datastore as well. I realized this yesterday when reproducing your error, since I had used two different logins to test, only one of which I also used during local testing. Then only the one I used in local testing expired after 1 hour, while the other one worked forever.

Answer (score 1):

In order to receive a refresh token, you need to have access_type=offline in the authorization request: https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2WebServer#offline

Note you will only get the refresh token once, together with the first access token.