# Google Surveys api - INVALID_CREDENTIALS

Tags: google-surveys

I try get surveys results through the api, but I am still getting an errors.
I am able to get google calendar events, but when I try get list of surveys, or results (https://www.googleapis.com/surveys/v2/surveys/{survey_ID}/results), I am getting:

```
"domain": "global",
"reason": "INVALID_CREDENTIALS",
"message": "User must be authenticated to make this call. Request Id: 5a73195500ff0c64532dccb0ef0001737e3430322d747269616c320001707573682d30312d33312d72313100010163",
"locationType": "header",
"location": "Authorization"
}
```

It looks like I have bad access token, but with same token and method, I get for example calendar events.
It looked like I have no scope, but when I issue this request `https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/tokeninfo?access_token={valid_token}` I get correct answer:

```
"issued_to": "822311642112-***********.apps.googleusercontent.com",
"audience": "822311642112-***********.apps.googleusercontent.com",
"scope": "https://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/ https://www.googleapis.com/auth/surveys",
"expires_in": 2983,
"access_type": "offline"
```

I have enabled Survey api in my account. I am running this code from visual foxpro desktop application over windows object Microsoft.XMLHTTP

Any idea what am I doing wrong?

EDIT:
This is not duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25389960) because my authentication credentials work fain with calendar, but not working with surveys. 
It looks like Maia Werbos has correct answer for me, now I am getting response that request is correct (status: 200), but response contains just requestId.

Maia thank you very much.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Invalid credentials: Google API calendar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25389960/invalid-credentials-google-api-calendar)

Comment: The message you get back tells you pretty clearly that your Credentials are Invalid.   You might get some more info over at:   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-api

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your request shows that you have the following two OAuth scopes enabled:

```
https://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/ 
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/surveys
```

But you also need to have the email scope enabled to use the Surveys API (see the Surveys API [Getting Started Guide](https://developers.google.com/surveys/v2/guides/getting-started-guide) for more info):

```
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email
```